# When do assists show up in the kill feed?

Tags: overwatch

Do you always get an assist if you've been doing damage? Multiple times now I've been firing at a target for some time, another player will drop in when they die and say 'Ha just took out 'X' on my own' and I'll say 'Nah I've been firing at them for ages' and they say 'You'd have got an assist if that were the case.'.

I don't have the assist picture in the kill feed, so they're right in that regard, but I know I've been doing significant damage. **So is there a time that you get an assist specifically? Does it only come up under certain circumstances? Or with a specific percentage of damage?**

[image: Kill assists in kill feed]

Comment: See also [How do I know if I got a kill assist in Overwatch?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/269780/145980)

Answer (score 5):

The new assist visual that shows up as of the new patches are for assists only, being a part of the kill (doing damage as you say you are) doesn't count as an assist, but rather an elimination. **If you've done damage to an enemy recently and someone else finishes them off you get credit towards the elimination as an elimination, not an assist.**

[From the late May update](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/game/patch-notes/pc/#patch-36859):

> - Your final blows are now highlighted by a white background in the Kill
> - Feed Added new Kill Feed icons for environmental kills and a number of
>     abilities
> - Heroes resurrected by Mercy are now are now highlighted and color-coded in the Kill Feed
> - **Certain types of assists, like McCree’s Flashbang or Zenyatta’s Orb of Discord, now show up in the Kill Feed**

**Ways to get assists are through means such as recon via Hanzo or Widowmaker, or offensive/defensive assists via Zenyatta's orbs. Other ways include healing/buffing from Mercy or sleep darts from Ana.**

Comment: @Phillip If the answer was sufficient and answered your question you can hit the green tick to accept the answer.